# Can I speed optimize the use of GridCellAttr in wxPython's wx.grid.Grid?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, wxgrid

I'm making a Windows application using `wx.grid.Grid` that will handle very large Microsoft Excel documents. Currently it opens a file with 17 columns and 12 000+ rows quite quickly, and I can scroll around smoothly. (This is a virtual table that operates on data from a custom table class.)

Anyway, the problem starts when I use custom grid cell attribute objects, e.g:

```
grid.SetAttr(row, col, SomeGridCellAttr('#FF0000'))
```

Once every cell in a row has a custom grid cell attribute, the performance of the grid just goes 99.9% into the toilet. Instead of smooth scrolling around I'm lucky if I get 1 redraw per 3 seconds. I fixed most of these instances by using `grid.SetColAttr` instead, which restored performance to it's previous smoothness, but there is ***one*** case where that won't work. The application iterates over every cell in a column (12 000 cells), performs some processing on the data and applies a custom grid cell attribute based on the results. Once that is done, the grid becomes a sluggish nightmare to work with.

Is there any way of removing this gruesome performance hit and retain the custom cell attributes? I suspect the answer is quite simple to somebody who knows the inner workings of the grid and it's cell attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: `The application iterates over every cell in a column (12 000 cells), performs some processing on the data and applies a custom grid cell attribute based on the results.` Maybe you could precalculate this once, put the results in a 2d-array and then, during scrolling, i.e., rendering of the cells, only access this array?

Comment: @ThorstenKranz: This is a virtual grid, meaning that I supplied a custom `wx.grid.PyGridTableBase` which loads data from an underlying table structure on demand, so the optimization you suggest should already be in play.

Comment: O.k., that's weird. Seems like something internal is at least not optimal. Then I can't help, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a cell attribute will add a new `GridCellAttr` to the list of the `GridCellAttrProvider`.
As the list grows, looking up a specific attribute for a cell (by iterating through the list and comparing the coordinates) gets slower and slower.

You can try to speed it up by implementing your own `PyGridTableBase.SetAttr` and `GetAttr` (using a dict for example):

**EDIT:** Updated code to allow overwriting attributes and emulate the default implementations attribute ownership.

```
class MyTable(wx.grid.PyGridTableBase):
    atts = {}

    def Hash(self,row,col):
        #FIXME: assumes a constant number of rows and rows > cols
        return col + row * self.GetNumberRows()

    def SetAttr(self,attr,row,col):
        HASH = self.Hash(row, col)
        if HASH in self.atts:
            # decrement usage count of existing attr
            self.atts[HASH].DecRef()
        #assign new attribute
        self.atts[HASH] = attr

    def GetAttr(self,row,col,kind):
        HASH = self.Hash(row, col)
        if HASH in self.atts:
            attr = self.atts[HASH]
            attr.IncRef() # increment reference count
            return attr
        return None
```

To allow setting entire rows and columns, you'll also have to implement:

```
    def SetRowAttr(self,attr,row):
        for col in range(self.GetNumberCols()):
            attr.IncRef() # increment reference count for SetAttr
            self.SetAttr(attr,row,col)
        attr.DecRef() # attr passed to SetRowAttr no longer needed

    def SetColAttr(self,attr,col):
        for row in range(self.GetNumberRows()):
            attr.IncRef() 
            self.SetAttr(attr,row,col)
        attr.DecRef()
```

**NOTE:** when passing a `GridCellAttr` to `Set*Attr()`, the default implementation will take ownership of the attribute.
To re-use the same attribute (stored in a class variable for example), you have to either `Clone()` it or increment its usage count (`IncRef()`) 
before passing it to a `Set*Attr()` method (cloning may increase memory consumption).

The above example lacks proper removal of attributes: `SetAttr()` could check for a None attr and decrement the ref count at the coordinates specified, then delete the entry from the dict.
`SetCol/RowAttr()` can be optimized by adding dicts for row and col, similar to `SetAttr()`. `GetAttr()` could then check for an existing entry in the row and col dict and merge/override the attribute(s) with the one from the cell dict (that's the principle used by the default implementation). For proper cleanup of the dict(s), call `DecRef` on every entry before `.clear()`.

Alternatively, you could derive from [`wx.grid.GridCellAttrProvider`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.GridCellAttrProvider-class.html)  and attach it with `PyGridTableBase.SetAttrProvider()`. This would prevent direct access to the table, however.

Comment: Is it safe to apply the same attribute instance to multiple cells? I'm sure I've had segmentation faults resulting from that, which is why I make sure to create a new instance every time. I think the function `GridCellAttr.IncRef` is related to that. Also, is that how `SetColAttr` is implemented under the hood? Because your example shows pretty much what I used to do, while switching to the `SetColAttr` method increased performance drastically. I did create a new attribute instance for every cell though..

Comment: @Codemonkey Internally, `wxGridCellAttrProviderData` has 3 arrays for cells, rows and cols that will store the attributes. That's why looking up a row or column is faster than a cell with the default implementation. Without increasing the ref count, the attributes are deleted once they are obtained by the cell renderer which seems to be causing your segfault. In the C++ source the ref count is incremented in wxGrid*AttrData::GetAttr(). While i didn't test it extensively, the above SetCol/RowAttr (reusing att for multiple cells) seems to work as intended.